# Merge multiple zip files on s3 into fewer zip files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a problem wherein some of the files in a s3 directory are in ~500MiB range, but many other files are in KiB and Bytes. I want to merge all the small files into fewer bigger files of the order of ~500MiB.

What is the most efficient way to rewriting data in an s3 folder instead of having to download, merge on local and push back to s3. Is there some utility/aws command i can use to achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

S3 is a storage service and has no compute capability. For what you are asking, you need compute (to merge). So you cannot do what you want without downloading, merging and uploading.