# Boto3 - python script to view all directories and files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I tried to follow the Boto3 examples, but can literally only manage to get the very basic listing of all my S3 buckets via the example they give:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

I cannot find documentation that explains how I would be able to traverse or change into folders and then access individual files.

I'm trying to get to my SNS delivery reports, which are stored in a folder for each day of the month - so it is a pain to manually have to download each file for the month and then to concatenate the contents of each file in order to get the count of all SMS messages sent for a month.

Does anyone have an example of a script that can help me with this, or pointers to really basic documentation/examples of helping me to do this?

I have 3 S3 buckets, and all the files are located in sub folders in one of them:

```
bucketname
|->Year
  |->Month
     |->Day1
     |->Day2
     |->Day3 
     |->Day4
```

etc etc
Underneath the "Day" folder is a single text file called 001.txt
SO I am trying to concatenate all the 001.txt files for each day of a month and then find the rowcount of the concatenated text file - which would give me the count of all SMS sent - successful and failed.

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: My answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351194/merge-multiple-zip-files-on-s3-into-fewer-zip-files - applies to your question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no folders, only S3 object keys.

Using the [Bucket Resource](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket) interface, you can filter the list of objects in a bucket using the [objects collection](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.objects) filter() method (see [example](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/collections.html#filtering)).

You can also use the [Client](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client) interface to call [list_objects()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) with a suitable prefix and delimiter to retrieve subsets of objects.

See [Listing Keys Hierarchically](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html) for a high-level description.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.

I tried the following and it looks like I can now see the list of all the individual text files for a specified month:

`import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('snssmsreports')
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='SMSUsageReports/eu-west-1/2018/01'):
    print('{0}:{1}'.format(bucket.name, obj.key))`

How do I "fetch" each file into a variable and concatenate it and then count the rows of said file?

PS - the files are listed as .csv.gz, so not sure if I am still looking at the object and not the actual file?

Comment: You should perhaps consider redesigning this. Maybe write a Lambda function that's triggered when a file is uploaded to the bucket. The Lambda function reads the file, counts the lines, and stores that count in DynamoDB, keyed by YYYYMMDD or similar.